# create radio buttons automatically from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, css

I am writing a python web app for google app engine using jinja2 though my problem relates to HTML/javascript (jquery is good).

I have a menu guided by radio buttons.  I have two columns that I want to permanently be there and I want the next three to be generated depending on what the user selects from the first two.

I understand somewhat how to generate the radio buttons automatically with JQuery (though any suggested resources would be great but I can probably figure it out) but my main question revolves around the fact that my final radio button has around 100 possibilities depending on the previous ones that are selected (only 3-5 will be displayed at a time mind you).

So my main question.  Where should I store the names for the radio buttons and URLs that they will lead to? and how do I put these into the radio buttons as they are created?

Here is an image of what I want the final product to look like:

[image]

Thanks so much this is bending my mind for some reason!

Answer (score 1):

Where are your 100 options stored now in javascript (front end)?

If all your options are stored on the front end you can implement your logic (which buttons to display based on the previous choices) on the front end. This would probably include an array of radio buttons.  As you can see this could start getting unweildy to maintaint.  Every time you want to update yoru logic you would have to manually update your js file.

If all the choices are stored in python/backend you will need to make an AJAX request from the front end to the backend.   This can be done easily using jquery framework.

This request would include the choices the user makes.  and it would return the correct radio buttons to display.

Comment: they aren't stored anywhere right now this is just a demo I made with one specific set of options.  So what kind of document could I refer to that had a list of a bunch of options?  would it need to be python with a bunch of if-then statements? or could it be a spreadsheet of some sort